# C# ¿Cómo puedo crear un archivo txt en memoria y mostrarlo?

Tags: c#, devexpress, silverlight

Estoy intentando crear un archivo de texto pero no quiero guardarlo en ninguna ruta, quisiera poder crearlo en memoria y mostrarlo y si el usuario quiere guardarlo, pues que lo haga desde el notepad *(o el programa predeterminado para abrir los archivos de texto)* cuando éste se muestre en pantalla.

Hasta el momento no tengo un ejemplo concreto que me sirva, solo tengo el siguiente código:

```
...
string memString = grr[0].Keys.ToArray()[0] + "," + grr[0].Keys.ToArray()[1] + "," + grr[0].Keys.ToArray()[2] + "," + grr[0].Keys.ToArray()[3];

byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(memString);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);

FileStream file = new FileStream("./file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
ms.WriteTo(file);
file.Close();
ms.Close();
...
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear el archivo de texto en memoria y luego mostrarlo en pantalla?

NOTA: Al mostrarlo en pantalla, no me refiero a mostrar el contenido, sino a que me ***abra el bloc de notas (o la aplicacion predeterminada)*** con el archivo que cree en memoria.

Comment: Actualmente me da un error al intentar crear el archivo porque no tiene acceso a la ruta, pero igualmente no quiero crearlo en una ruta fisica, quiero crearle en memoria

Comment: Por lo que he visto no tenes una manera de hacerlo directamente con los comandos de notepad++.
Aqui te dejo el listado de comandos:
http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches

Comment: es una aplicacion en c# en la que tengo un conjunto de datos que quiero visualizar en un archivo de texto (archivo.txt), no tiene nada que ver con los comandos de notepad

Comment: En cuanto al notepad Microsoft las opciones son menos y todas requieren de un archivo:
/A <filename> abrir archivo como ANSI
/W <filename> abrir archivo como Unicode

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389

Comment: Vos podes mostrar un cuadro de texto en un WinForm o WPF y guardarlo como un archivo de texto.
Si pudieras aclarar un poco lo que intentas hacer quizás te podamos guiar un poco más.

Comment: debajo del codigo que comparti en la pregunta lo dije, pense que estaba claro: como puedo hacer para crear el archivo de texto en memoria y luego mostrarlo en pantalla?? (ojo...al mostrarlo en pantalla, no me refiero a mostrar el contenido, sino a que me abra el block de notas (o la aplicacion predeterminada) con el archivo que cree en memoria)

Comment: LO que quiero es crear un archivo txt pero no en una ruta fisica del equipo, quiero crearlo en memoria y lluego quiero mostrarlo tal cual como  cuando se hace cuando se "exporta a excel" lo que se hace es crear un "Application" de tipo excel en memoria si arma la hoja de calculo, las columnas las celdas y luego se muestra....el mostrar lo que hace es que reconoce que el archivo que creaste es de extension xls y sabe que ese archivo se ejecuta con excel y abre automaticamente excel y te muestra tu archivo exportado....

Comment: quiero hacer lo mismo con un archivo txt...poder crearlo en memoria y al querer mostrarlo...el pc reconozca que es un archivo de extension .txt y ejecute a la aplicacion necesaria (notepad, word, wordpad, etc..) para mostrarlo

Comment: @LuisAcuña, en la aplicación que estás desarrollando, ¿no puedes colocar un RichTextBox u otro elemento que sirva de contenedor del texto que deseas mostrar y que el usuario final pueda editar?, Básicamente crea una nueva pantalla que tenga un contenedor del texto y un botón de guardar. Cuando el usuario guarda los cambios, continuas con el flujo de tu programa: _guardar en base de datos, imprimir, etc_.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave la idea es precisamente no editar desde la aplicacion...el comportamiento es mas como un exportar a txt

Comment: Debido a que no puedo encontrar una solucion a mi interrogante, dare por cerrado el tema. Habrá que buscar otra forma de hacer lo que necesito.

Comment: Ando buscando lo mismo, encontraste una solución? En mi caso es una funcion javascript que tiene que leer un archivo pero ese archivo necesito que este en memoria.

Answer (score 1):

Si realmente necesitas enviarlo al bloc de notas sin pasar por el disco podrías usar la solución propuesta aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613576/how-to-open-text-in-notepad-from-net

Uso de la clase:

```
NotepadHelper.ShowMessage("My message...", "My Title");
```

Clase NotepadHelper:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Notepad
{
    public static class NotepadHelper
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowText")]
        private static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

    public static void ShowMessage(string message = null, string title = null)
    {
        Process notepad = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe"));
        if (notepad != null)
        {
            notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
                SetWindowText(notepad.MainWindowHandle, title);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, message);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Como puedes ver el código arranca el proceso "notepad.exe", por lo que siempre se mostraría en bloc de notas ignorando cualquier aplicación predeterminada que el usuario pueda tener configurada.

Comment: no necesariamente debe ser con notepad, lo que importa es que el archivo se ejecute con cualquier aplicacion predeterminada para abrir archivos de texto, bien sea notepad, wordpad, word, etc. El punto es poder crear el archivo mediante programación (en memoria) sin tener que utilizar una ruta para almacenarlo. No quiero restringir a que solo sea notepad porque pueda que alguien lo ejecute desde un equipo que no tenga windows

Comment: El ejemplo anterior no necesita ninguna ruta para almacenarlo, se envía directamente a la ventana de edición del bloc de notas, pero precisamente porque usa funciones del SO para obtener la ventana y escribir en ella solo funciona para Windows. No he leído nada en la pregunta que indicara que la aplicación es multiplataforma... usas .NET Core? Puedes dar más detalles de el entorno?

Comment: es una aplicacion web asp que utiliza silverlight

Comment: Entonces entiendo que se debería hacer desde el mismo silverlight, no? Te recomiendo que añadas el tag silverlight a ver si alguien que tenga experiencia puede ayudarte.

Comment: es verdad, lastimosamente no me permite añadir nuevas etiquetas en la edicion, no tengo ese "privilegio" aun :(

Comment: @LuisAcuña, ya he agregado la etiqueta y he editado tu pregunta. Yo te recomiendo buscar si puedes usar Process.Start y pasarle el texto a mostrar a esa instancia del editor de texto de tu preferencia *(esto último no lo he hecho)*. Creo que va mas allá de lo que preguntas, pero, debes revisar alguna manera de limitar o consultar cuáles editores de texto poseen los equipos "sistemas operativos" para usar el código que buscas, o puedes "imponer" que para que funcione tu programa, deben instalar notepad++ y con el código que provee esta respuesta, te puede funcionar.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave intente con Process.Start y no me funcionó sin embargo voy a intentar con este codigo a ver como me va, si me funciona sera dejar "mientras tanto" una nota aclaratoria en la que se diga que se debe usar con el notepad

Comment: A la final tampoco me funciono.... -_-

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de guardar texto con saltos de linea a un archivo txt y mostrarlo con notepad es:

```
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;

    namespace StringToFile
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Creacion texto en memoria
                StringBuilder constructor = new StringBuilder();
                constructor.AppendLine("Hola");
                constructor.AppendLine("Mundo!");

                //Persistencia
                string pathTxt = @".\miArchivo.txt";
                File.WriteAllText(pathTxt, constructor.ToString());

                //Lo muestro en el notepad
                Process.Start("notepad.exe",pathTxt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: bueno estas creando el archivo en una ruta fisica (pathTxt) y es lo que quiero evitar. hace que me salga una excepcion que dice: Operación de archivo no permitida. Acceso a la ruta '.\miArchivo.txt' denegado.

Comment: lo que busco es no tener que crear el archivo fisico, por eso pregunto, como poder crearlo de manera "virtual"